# Help needed installing OS X 10.6 on a clean iMac 8.1/early 2008

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, imac, startup

I have an iMac that has had the hard drive wiped completly clean, no partitions at all, just a blank drive, I have purchased OS X 10.6 installation DVD.  I try to install OS X, the disc loads up and then after approx 4 minutes the light grey screen scrolls to a dark grey screen and the Mac has a message in the middle of the screen telling me to turn if off and back on again, if I do this, the process just keep repeating itself.

It's an Intel-based Mac, so I tried to install Windows 7 which worked nicely, but I still want to install OS X.

Can any one offer any advice please on how to get out of the boot loop when installing the OS X?

Comment: Is the message like the one here? http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742 - http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/TS3742/en_US/TS3742_01_KP-001-en.jpg

Comment: iMac 8.1 would be an early 2008 model which should work with 10.6. Are you sure it's an 8.1 model?

Comment: Yes the message in the pic is the exact same one, the 8.1 model, yes I'm sure it is, the model number off the base of the machine is A1225  Thanks very much fpr the replies